# Convert Word document to base64 string C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to get the base64 representation of an active Word document while it's still open in Word
and am getting the following error in ReadAllBytes():

**The process cannot access the file 'file path' it is being used by another process**

```
public string GetEncodedTemplate()
        {
            //Convert a Word document's base64 representation
            string base64 = String.Empty;
            _application.ActiveDocument.Save();

            string docPath = _application.ActiveDocument.FullName;
            byte[] binarydata = File.ReadAllBytes(docPath);
            base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binarydata, 0, binarydata.Length);
            return base64;
        }
```

I do understand that the error occurs because the specified document is still open in Word,
my question is - Is it still somehow possible to get the base64 representation of the document without resorting to saving to a temp file?

I'm using C# .NET 4.0
And MS Office 2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct - Word has a lock on the current document. In order to get the current document bytes you would need to **copy the existing file** ([`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx)) or **save to a new file** ([`Document.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`IPersistFile.Save`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranavwagh/archive/2008/04/03/how-to-do-a-save-copy-as-in-word.aspx)) for reading its content.